# PHP Dynamic Breadcrumbs - How To Hide Duplicates?

Tags: php, dynamic, foreach, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to get rid of duplicate items in my dynamic breadcrumbs.

```
    //$url = substr(strstr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 'admin'), 6);
    $url = substr(strstr('/content/modal/admin/content/timeline/timeline', 'admin'), 6);
    $parse_url = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, "."));

    $array = explode("/", $parse_url);

    if($array[0] == 'index') {
        echo 'CMP';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="javascript:;" onclick="initializemodal(\'content/modal/admin/index\')">Staff</a> / ';

        $path = [];
        foreach($array as $value) {
            $path[] = $value;

            echo '<a href="javascript:;" onclick="initializemodal(\'content/modal/admin/' . implode('/', $path) . '\')">' . $value . '</a> / ';
        }
    }
```

This outputs as:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="initializemodal('content/modal/admin/index')">Staff</a> /
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="initializemodal('content/modal/admin/content')">content</a> /
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="initializemodal('content/modal/admin/content/timeline')">timeline</a> /
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="initializemodal('content/modal/admin/content/timeline/timeline')">timeline</a> /
```

As you can see it also lists the directory on the 3rd line. The 4th line is the file itself.

How can I make it so it keeps the duplicate in the URL, but skips the link itself? To clarify, how can I get this output instead?:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="initializemodal('content/modal/admin/index')">Staff</a> /
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="initializemodal('content/modal/admin/content')">content</a> /
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="initializemodal('content/modal/admin/content/timeline/timeline')">timeline</a> /
```

Comment: you can just check if the next index of your $array is same as current value then continue for skip this loop

Comment: @EmtiazZahid Do you mean `if(current($array) == end($array)) continue;`?

Comment: yes, is it work like that ?

Comment: @EmtiazZahid unfortunately it does not seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your loop to this:

```php
    foreach($array as $index => $value) {
        $path[] = $value;
        //skip current element if next element is identically
        if($value == $array[$index+1]) continue;

        echo '<a href="javascript:;" onclick="initializemodal(\'content/modal/admin/' . implode('/', $path) . '\')">' . $value . '</a> / ';
    }
```

It will skip an element in the array, if the next element is the same. 
So when there are duplicate entries (but just directly following), only the last one of this entries (and his full url) is printed out

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot.